# Buscar rango de fechas dia mes año en formato String de mongodb

Tags: mongodb

En la base de datos de mongodb tengo almacenado fechas (dia/mes/año) en formato string y quiero consultar un rango de fechas. Soy nuevo usando mongodb por lo que no he encontrado como resolverlo

Comment: Creo que la tienes muy complicada, porque los strings no tienen rango. Lo ideal sería almacenar las fechas como fechas en mongodb. La unica que se me ocurriría (si el rango no es muy grande) es generar un array de fechas del rango deseado y consultar la base de datos con un `$in` por ejemplo, si el campo se llama "fecha", entonces algo como `{ fecha: { $in: ["01/01/2022", "02/01/2022", "03/01/2022"]}` suponiendo que el rango de fechas es de 3 dias.

Comment: Acabo de ver... si usas agreggate puedes usar `$dateFromString` y con eso ya podrías hacer un search basado en fecha inicio y fecha final